# Yii form validation: variable containing the error

Tags: validation, variables, error-handling, yii

I'm using a gridview as a form in yii. If I have a validation error for example for a textfield, how can I access the variable that stores the fact of error? Because I would like to change background color of the grid based on this.
I have this in a gridview's column (because I do it with [a little trick](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/44002-multiple-model-save/page__view__findpost__p__211696)):

```
array( 'value' => 'CHtml::textField("OrderProduct[$row][pcs]",
    $_POST["OrderProduct"][$row]["pcs"],
    array("id" => "OrderProduct_" . $row . "_pcs", "style" => "width: 20px; "))',
    'type' => 'raw', ),
```

but I think the error should be there somewhere, and should have some ID or something, but I can't find it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you use CActiveForm or do you use a CModel?

Comment: I'm using GxActiveForm

Comment: Okay. Do you have something like this in your view: `$form->error($model, 'myField');` ?

Comment: it would be easier if you paste the form view code here.